# How would one print table outputs in python into latex?

Tags: python, pythontex

So, Let's say I have outputs of the following form:

[image]

How would one insert this output into latex? I have tried using `verbatim` but I didn't like the result I wanted.

Comment: It depends on how these tables are produced in Python. Some libraries (like pandas) have functionality to generate LaTeX code. If the library that you have doesn't offer export to LaTeX or to some intermediate format that can further be transformed into LaTeX (like csv for example) then the only option is to write the table in LaTeX by hand or maybe to write some Python code to generate the LaTeX code for you if you have access to the code that produced the current output.

Comment: I have access to the code, but its quite big and this tables were formatted by me (with appropriate print commands). Is there a solution for this or are pictures the way to go?

Comment: If you wrote the print commands then you can also write a bit of code around it for a tabular header, cell separators and line endings. I can show a small example below.

Answer (score 5):

If you control the print statements creating the current output then you can also write print statements to generate LaTeX code. Simple example:

Python:

```python
headers = ["x 1","x 2","x 3","x 4","x 5","bbar"]
data = dict()
data["x 4"] = [1,2,3,1,0,9]
data["x 5"] = [3,2,2,0,1,15]
data["z"] = [1,9,3,0,0,0]

textabular = f"l|{'r'*len(headers)}"
texheader = " & " + " & ".join(headers) + "\\\\"
texdata = "\\hline\n"
for label in sorted(data):
   if label == "z":
      texdata += "\\hline\n"
   texdata += f"{label} & {' & '.join(map(str,data[label]))} \\\\\n"

print("\\begin{tabular}{"+textabular+"}")
print(texheader)
print(texdata,end="")
print("\\end{tabular}")
```

Generated LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|rrrrrr}
 & x 1 & x 2 & x 3 & x 4 & x 5 & bbar\\
\hline
x 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 9 \\
x 5 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 15 \\
\hline
z & 1 & 9 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This would be cool for a small task... but considering I have more like 50 outputs like the one I posted, this get a bit tricky and too much work, but that's a good way to solve the problem!

Comment: @roro the idea is that if the data is organized in Python in a similar way (for example your two tables above have exactly the same size and structure, only different numbers and slightly different rownames) then you can use the same Python code to parse this. For example in the above you only need to change the three lines defining the `data` dictionary and then the code below, unchanged, will generate the second table. Depending on how complex your data is you might need to add in some extra Python logic.

Comment: @roro More than 50 such tables would suggest using a function to populate the data but you haven't given any details on how the data is determined. I don't know `pythontex`; I use the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) package for Python (plus a CAS). See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500019/filling-the-latex-table-dynamically/500087#500087) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482495/programmatically-populating-tables-with-probability-data/482517#482517) for some examples. I would think `pythontex` can do this as well.

Comment: @Marijn I think you could prepend ‘r’ before string in Python, e.g. r”\hline”, to avoid multiple escaping of backslashes.

Comment: @Celdor you are right (although it wouldn't combine nicely with `f""` I guess), I decided not to spend too much effort on making the Python code clean and readable :)

Comment: Both `r` and `f` work together but you are right it may not be worth the effort :). I understand I am probably in the wrong place pointing at something of little importance but I always consider using r"" to avoid multiple backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the above answers that use print statements for generating the Latex code: there is a Python library called `latextable` for doing exactly this https://github.com/JAEarly/latextable

There's also guidance on how to use it here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-latex-tables-directly-from-python-code-5228c5cea09a

*Full disclosure - I am the author of this library.*

Comment: This seems like an interesting solution. Maybe you can improve the answer here by showing (with a code example and a screenshot of the output) how the library can be applied in the current case?